# Wordpress logo only working on front page nothing else

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a website and the logo works on the front page but on the other pages the links seem to be broken and no images are showing.

http://utahtraveldirectory.com  is the front page and for example http://utahtraveldirectory.com/hotel-search/ the logo isn't working.

I checked all the permissions and I think they are fine, maybe I wasn't checking the right folder?
I won't leave the site up for long but I needed some help! Thanks!

I am using the YooTheme - Lava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to the logo is broken on the the other pages except for the homepage. If you use the inspect element window on Safari you will see that the link is broken on the other pages. It's definitely not a permissions problem.

The link to the picture on the homepage is http://utahtraveldirectory.com/wp-content/uploads/yootheme/utah-travel-logo.png but the link on the other pages to the logo is http://utahtraveldirectory.com/hotel-search/wp-content/uploads/yootheme/utah-travel-logo.png. The first link is where the picture actually is.

Comment: How do I change the link on there? because it should all be the same

Comment: From what I am looking at the path that links to the image is different on the homepage than any other page. I followed that link and it does link to the actual image file. I'm not sure if there is a way in WordPress to edit the actual HTML but I think the easiest thing to do is to export your site to a local folder on your computer and edit the HTML manually. As for the color changes between browsers, I have no explanation for that. Maybe some faulty code with the theme that is not cross-platform compatible? Good luck.

Comment: That's the problem.. I don't know why it is saying it's a different link because the theme should leave that the same. I cleared the cache and realized that the colors changed, so that was my bad

Comment: True. It _should_ be the same but obviously it isn't. What FTP client are you using? Is it a graphical or command-line client? Just download the folder "wp-content" from your website and look for your homepage's HTML file. Open it up and you will see towards the top the link to the image file. Open another page's HTML file and copy the homepage's link to the other page. See if that works. If it does, then do the same for all of your pages. There may be a simpler way to do it but I am not too familiar with WordPress. Maybe a "Choose File" button in a control panel?

Comment: I went into the widget that was holding the logo and instead of putting just the path, I put the whole url and it worked... figures it was something simple. Thank you!

Comment: Just visited your website. Looks like you figured it out. :) No problem.